# Implication in Zassenhaus Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I need to proof Zassenhaus Lemma using the First Isomorphism Theorem and I have a problem with the following implication:

> $H' \vartriangleleft H < G, K' \vartriangleleft K < G \Longrightarrow H'(H \cap K') \vartriangleleft H'(H \cap K) < H.$

I have shown that $H \cap K' \vartriangleleft H \cap K, $ but I don't see why $H'(H \cap K') \vartriangleleft H'(H \cap K)$. It should follow from the First Isomorphism Theorem and from $H' \vartriangleleft H,$ but I don't see how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it is more clear if you prove the following:

> Claim: If $C \trianglelefteq H$ and $A \trianglelefteq B \leq H$, then $CA \trianglelefteq CB \leq H$.

Then your claim follows with $C = H'$ and $A = H \cap K'$, $B = H \cap K$. Note that in this situation $A \trianglelefteq B$  since $K' \trianglelefteq K$.

Maybe you want to try to prove the claim yourself. If you get stuck, here is a proof:

> $CA$ and $CB$ are subgroups since $C$ is normal, and $CA \leq CB$ is obvious. Now $B$ normalizes $CA$ since $C$ is normal, and since $A \trianglelefteq B$. Furthermore, $C$ normalizes $CA$ since $C$ is a subgroup of $CA$. Thus $CB$ normalizes $CA$, that is, $CA \trianglelefteq CB$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I also like your answer, this looks a bit easier!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the whole Zassenhaus Lemma is a straithforward application of the Second Isomorphism Theorem which states:

> If $H\subseteq N_G(K),$ then $HK = KH$ and $H/(H\cap K)\cong HK/K$

*(where $N_G(K)$ denotes the normalizer of $K$ in $G$, and all the appropriate subgroups can be verified to be normal)*

Let me change your notation a bit (so I can relate it to 2nd isomorphism theorem easier). Let $U$ and $V$ be subgroups of $G$, $u\trianglelefteq U$, $v\trianglelefteq V$ be normal subgroups. Then Zassenhaus Lemma claims that $$u(U\cap V)/u(U\cap v)\cong (U\cap V)v/(u\cap V)v.$$

The proof uses symmetry; if we could prove that $$u(U\cap V)/ u(U\cap v)\cong (U\cap V)/(u\cap V)(U\cap v)$$
 then by symmetry we would have $$(U\cap V)v/(u\cap V)v\cong (U\cap V)/(u\cap V)(U\cap v)$$ as well, and this would be the end of the proof.

So, let us denote $H = U\cap V$ and $K = u (U\cap v)$. I leave it as an exercise (and will write it down if requested) to prove that $$H\subseteq N_G(K),$$  $$u(U\cap V) = u(U\cap v)(U\cap V),$$ and $$(U\cap V)\cap u(U\cap v) = (u\cap V)(U\cap v).$$

The rest is the 2nd Isomorphism Theorem.

**Edit:**

You want to prove that $K$ is normal in $HK$ (in my notation). As I noted, this is a part of the proof of the Second Isomorphism Theorem.

Let us assume that $H\subseteq N_G(K)$. Then obviously $HK = KH$ and it is  a one liner to prove that $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$: $$(hk)(h'k') = hh'\underbrace{(h')^{-1}kh'}_{\in K}k'\in HK$$ (almost, since $(hk)^{-1}=k^{-1}h^{-1} \in KH = HK$)

*$K$ is normal in $HK$:*

Let $h\in H$, $k\in K$, $x\in K$,

$$(hk)x(hk)^{-1} = h\underbrace{kxk^{-1}}_{\in K}h^{-1} \in K$$ because $h\in N_G(K)$.

This answers your inquiry.

But it still remains unanswered why $u(U\cap V)(U\cap v) = u (U\cap V)$ (i.e. why $HK =  u (U\cap V)$ in my notation). Well, both the inclusions are obvious if you observe that $U\cap v \subseteq U\cap V$, so $(U\cap V)(U\cap v) = U\cap V$.

Also, why is $U\cap V\in N_G(u(U\cap v))$? Let $x\in U\cap V$ and $u_0v_0\in u(U\cap v)$. Then $$ x(u_0v_0) = u_0'xv_0 = u_0'v_0'x$$ where $u_0'\in u$ since $u_0\in u$ and $u$ is normal in $U$ (and $x\in U\cap V$); and $v_0'\in v$, since $v_0\in v$ and $v$ is normal in $V$ (and $x\in U\cap V$). The only question is whether $v_0'\in U$, but that follows immediately from $xv_0 = v_0'x\implies v_0' = xv_0x^{-1}\in U$. This proves $x(U\cap v) = (U\cap v)x$, for any $x\in U\cap V$, and thus $U\cap V\in N_G(u(U\cap v))$.

Comment: Addendum: I really do recommend Lang's Algebra where appropriate diagram can be found. The diagram is much more clear then any proof could be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! With First I. T.  I mean the one that you called Second I. T. (it seems that in Switzerland, Germany etc. we have an other naming convention).

I actually understood the whole proof made in the lecture, only the point that I named is not clear to me, so I'd like to complete the proof that I already know... 

In my lecture notes it says "apply the Second I. T.". Could you please write down, how do I make that step? Thank you!

Comment: I hope that it is of help. If any clarification is needed, please say so. I'm not sure about particular nomenaclature, but usually 1st I.T. states that $G/\ker f\cong \operatorname{im}f$, and what I state as 2nc I.T. is just the application to epimorphism $h\mapsto hK\colon H\to HK/K$ which has kernel $H\cap H$. Let me write down the details in a bit...

Comment: @nbayo, please read what I just edited to see if it answers your question. To your comment, the answer is _probably_ yes.  All I'm claiming is that I can apply [2nd I.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Second_isomorphism_theorem).

Comment: Sorry, I saw only now, that you've already answered! My connectin is a bit crazy. I'll read :)

Comment: "leave as an exercise", "one liner",  "obvious",  "straightforward"... have you been reading Lang's Algebra book by chance?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, hehe, yes I have, of course, and I know exactly what you mean. But, actually, algebra is strong at my university, so I really do feel this way (not to be obnoxious).

Comment: It is still obnoxious, regardless of all that. :)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, I should probably work on that, thank you for the comment. :)

Comment: Haven't you shown now that $u(U \cap v) \vartriangleleft U \cap V$? I actually need to show that $u(U \cap v) \vartriangleleft u(U \cap V)$. Or does it follow directly?

Comment: @nbayo, I've shown that $U\cap V$ is in normalizer of $ u(U\cap v)$ (i.e. $H\in N_G(K)$ in my notation) which I proved implies that $u(U\cap v)$ is normal in $u(U\cap V)$ (i.e. $K$ is normal in $HK$). Please check again the part where I do prove that $u(U\cap V) = u(U\cap V)(U\cap v)$ (i.e. $=HK$).

Comment: The notation is very confusing, since you use small letters for subgroups. Usually people use capital letters for subgroups and small letters for elements.

Comment: @spin, might be the case. This is notation used in Lang's Algebra. I'd usually agree with you, but in this particular case I actually think it works better,

Comment: @Ennar Ok, I've read and this is clear now. Thank you!

Comment: @nbayo I'm glad. This came out a bit too long, but is actually (almost) the whole proof of the Lemma.